# Is there a way to fill multiple fields using onclick method

Tags: javascript, html

I have a matrix of images. Each image currently fills a specific field with information. Code for one image below.

```html
 <a href="#riskrating1" data-toggle="tab"><img src="components/com_safety101/images/a2.jpg" width="72" height="32" border="0" onclick="document.getElementById('jform_pre_control_risk').value = '10: Undesirable'; " /></a>
```

Is there a way that each image could fill three fields with different information? Not sure if you can stack the document.get ElementById calls?

Comment: I assume there must be a pattern to fill input element..

Answer (score 2):

The statement in the `onclick` attribute **can contain any number of JavaScript statements**.
You can write a whole program in it if you want - just that it's going to look terrible.

It is more advisable to put what you want to achieve with the `onclick` inside a separate function:

```
<a href="#riskrating1" data-toggle="tab">
    <img src="components/com_safety101/images/a2.jpg"
         width="72" height="32" border="0"
         onclick="handleOnClickFor(this)" />
</a>
```

and add a JavaScript function:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function handleOnClickFor (element){
        // 'element' would be the DOM Object for the <img> tag,
        // differentiate different images with arguments like this
        // Note that the arguments can be a string, number, object ...
        document.getElementById('jform_pre_control_risk').value = '10: Undesirable'; 
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You would extract the code to a javascript function:

```
<a href="#riskrating1" data-toggle="tab">
    <img 
        src="components/com_safety101/images/a2.jpg" 
        width="72" height="32" border="0" 
        onclick="populateFields()" />
</a>

<script type="text/javascript">
     function populateFields() {
         document.getElementById('jform_pre_control_risk').value = '10: Undesirable';
         // Populate other fields here
         document.getElementById('other_id').value = 'some other value';
     }
</script>
```